# How to programmatically fail fast an entire spec suite

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a test suite where occasionally the suite loses it's database connection or something like that and starts throwing mysql errors for most of the remaining tests. I'll trouble shoot why that is happening later. but right now, I wanted to just cause rspec to fail fast when it detects that particular type of error is being thrown. Is there anyway to do that, perhaps in an after block that checks if there was an exception in the main test block, and then sends a command to spec to fail fast? I don't want to use fail fast in most other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use the raise_error matcher to specify that a block of code raises an error. The most
basic form passes if any error is thrown:

```
  expect { #put your code here }.to raise_error
```

Please refer https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher

Comment: This doesn't cause the suite to fail. in fact, quite the opposite. I want specific types of errors to prevent any further tests from running. I Hope my question was clear about that.

Comment: If one of the example fails, then further whole spec should get failed?
With same error, right?

Comment: Well, more like the rest of the test suite should not be run, like the fail-fast mode spec has built in, but I want to programmatically trigger it based on a custom condition, and not the built-in condition (fail fast when any error occurs).